# RCurl not working in download of URL content

Tags: xml, r, rcurl, rvest

The download of the page doesn't work.  Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error in which(value == defs) : 
  argument "code" is missing, with no default
```

Here is my code:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)

ok <- "http://www.okcupid.com/match?filter1=0,34&filter2=2,22,40&filter3=3,5&filter4=5,3600&filter5=9,486&filter6=1,1&locid=4265540&lquery=San%20Francisco,%20California&timekey=1&matchOrderBy=MATCH&custom_search=0&fromWhoOnline=0&mygender=m&update_prefs=1&sort_type=0&sa=1&using_saved_search=&count=50"

okc <- getURL(ok, encoding="UTF-8") #Download the page
okcHTML <- htmlParse(okc, asText = TRUE, encoding = "utf-8")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're willing to live on the cutting edge of the Hadleyverse, `rvest` is handling this quite well:

```
library(rvest)

ok_search <- "https://www.okcupid.com/match?filter1=0,34&filter2=2,22,40&filter3=3,5&filter4=5,3600&filter5=9,486&filter6=1,1&locid=4265540&lquery=San%20Francisco,%20California&timekey=1&matchOrderBy=MATCH&custom_search=0&fromWhoOnline=0&mygender=m&update_prefs=1&sort_type=0&sa=1&using_saved_search=&count=50"

pg <- html_session(ok_search)
pg %>% html_nodes("div.profile_info") %>% html_text()

##  [1] "  phenombom   32·San Francisco, CA  "        "  sylvea   24·San Francisco, CA  "          
##  [3] "  haafu   40·San Francisco, CA  "            "  Rebamania   31·San Francisco, CA  "       
##  [5] "  Brilikedacheese   26·San Francisco, CA  "  "  cloudhunteress   23·San Francisco, CA  "  
##  [7] "  Lizzieisdizzy   28·San Francisco, CA  "    "  liddybird80   34·San Francisco, CA  "     
##  [9] "  wander_found   32·San Francisco, CA  "     "  Crunchyisinabox   31·San Francisco, CA  " 
...
```

I'll poke at why straight `RCurl` (`rvest` wraps `RCurl`) isn't working.

**UPDATE**

Went one level deeper and used `httr` (another `RCurl` abstraction):

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

res <- GET(ok_search)
ok_html <- content(res, as="parsed")
xpathSApply(ok_html, "//div[@class='profile_info']", xmlValue)
```

It returns the same as above, so that's working fine, too.

**UPDATE** / **SOLVED**

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

okc <- getURL(ok,  followlocation=TRUE)
ok_html <- htmlParse(okc)
xpathSApply(ok_html , "//div[@class='profile_info']", xmlValue)
```

You need to add `followlocation=TRUE`. The original URL is causing a `302` response (the server is sending a redirect) and `RCurl` won't follow those by default, but it seems `httr` and `rvest` ensure that parameter is set by default.

You can use the `verbose=TRUE` parameter on `getURL` to see the responses as console messages:

```
## * Adding handle: conn: 0x114ade000
## * Adding handle: send: 0
## * Adding handle: recv: 0
## * Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
## * - Conn 12 (0x114ade000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
## * About to connect() to www.okcupid.com port 80 (#12)
## *   Trying 198.41.209.131...
## * Connected to www.okcupid.com (198.41.209.131) port 80 (#12)
## > GET /match?filter1=0,34&filter2=2,22,40&filter3=3,5&filter4=5,3600&filter5=9,486&filter6=1,1&locid=4265540&lquery=San%20Francisco,%20California&timekey=1&matchOrderBy=MATCH&custom_search=0&fromWhoOnline=0&mygender=m&update_prefs=1&sort_type=0&sa=1&using_saved_search=&count=50 HTTP/1.1
## User-Agent: curl/7.30.0 Rcurl/1.95.4.3
## Host: www.okcupid.com
## Accept: */*
## 
## < HTTP/1.1 302
## < Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 20:07:12 GMT
## < Content-Type: application/octet-stream
## < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
## < Connection: keep-alive
## < Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d0d55f2c9c990d97b0d02dba7148881741413835631999; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.okcupid.com; HttpOnly
## < X-OKWS-Version: OKWS/3.1.30.2
## < Location: https://www.okcupid.com/match?filter1=0,34&filter2=2,22,40&filter3=3,5&filter4=5,3600&filter5=9,486&filter6=1,1&locid=4265540&lquery=San%20Francisco,%20California&timekey=1&matchOrderBy=MATCH&custom_search=0&fromWhoOnline=0&mygender=m&update_prefs=1&sort_type=0&sa=1&using_saved_search=&count=50
## < P3P: CP="NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND UNI COM NAV INT", policyref="http://www.okcupid.com/w3c/p3p.xml"
## < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
## < Set-Cookie: guest=10834912674894888479; Expires=Tue, 20 Oct 2015 20:07:12 GMT; Path=/; Domain=okcupid.com; HttpOnly
## * Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
## < Server: cloudflare-nginx
## < CF-RAY: 17c7d71bf1880412-EWR
## < 
## * Connection #12 to host www.okcupid.com left intact
```

It's very useful in debugging problems such as this. you can use a  `verbose()` parameter to `httr` or `rvest` URL retrieval functions as well.

Comment: I get the following error when I try this code:> okc <-  getURL(ok, followlocation=TRUE) #Download the page
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: That's a sign of out of date certs on your system. You can pass `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE` to `getURL` or `getURLContent` but it'll make @Hadley kill another kitten.

Comment: The [RCurl FAQ](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html) is a good bookmark to have on hand for web scraping.

Comment: I really prefer css selectors: `html_nodes("div.profile_info")` - much less typing!

Comment: Totally agree, @hadley, but Austin had the `XML` library in the OP and I was just trying to get his `RCurl` problem solved without adding that into the mix (I only included the `xpathSApply` to show it worked an potentially stave off a secondary question :-)

Comment: Oh, man, @hadley, I didn't realize I slipped into a faux combo of XML & CSS in the first part. Too focused on the URL retrieval issue. `#fixing`